# Angular UI-Router - How to access .php files in public_html folder?

Tags: php, angular-ui-router

I am new to the community. I hope I am following the rules.

I am deploying an website/Angular app and there is a .php based admin app in the same `directory/folder (public_html)`. Users still need to be able to access .php pages in the same directory/folder as the Angular app's index.html. By default, Angular seems to intercept the request for any file with a .php extension and routes it as `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');` to `website.com/#/.`

Can anyone offer guidance?

I am not sure if it is helpful, but here is the routing piece from my app.js file:

```
.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider',   function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider

      .state('home', {  
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      })
      .state('stores', { 
        url: '/stores',
        templateUrl: 'templates/stores.html',
        controller: 'storesCtrl'
      })
      .state('search', {
        url: '/search',
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
        controller: 'searchCtrl'
      })
      .state('style-guide', {
        url: '/style-guide/:styleId',
        templateUrl: 'templates/style-guide.html',
        controller: 'styleGuideCtrl'
      })
      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'templates/about.html'
        /* controller: 'aboutCtrl' */
      })
      .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: 'templates/contact.html'
        /* controller: 'contactCtrl' */
      })
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
      })
```

Comment: can you clarify your question what does it mean they need to access php files? when you have web server configured on http://localhost, and you are requestin http://localhost/test.php, i am 100% sure that you will get your php unless htaccess or nginx config is not rewriting all requests to index.html file.

Comment: Thank you. You answered my question by asking for more info. I am new here. Can you post your comment in the form of an answer so I can up vote your answer? I think that is how it works.